# Why is this question not off topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

A question, [asked years ago](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/13618/randomly-generating-weather-for-a-sandbox-campaign), was voted closed as off topic by the community.  It is a shopping question, and all shopping questions no matter how good or bad were [deemed off-topic](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5747/are-game-recommendation-questions-on-topic-revisited).

It was reopened by the moderator who deemed all shopping questions off topic.

What gives?

I genuinely want to know the difference between an acceptable shopping question and an unacceptable one; given the foreknowledge that there is an 'acceptable' shopping question, I still would have voted to close that one.  I am rather confused.

Comment: I feel like it could go either way, myself. I recuse myself from this question and acting on that one. :)

Comment: See: http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/5787/i-want-to-ask-for-recommendations-but-thats-off-topic-is-there-any-way-to-ask

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Mxy explains in a comment on that question quite clearly what the distinction is:

> [...] it asks for a method [...], as opposed to asking for a specific product.

This makes it not a shopping question. It's not an "acceptable shopping question," it's "the 'good form' of **what would otherwise be** a shopping question." ([emphasis mine](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6537/4398))

It's as simple as that, and a basic premise of good Stack questions everywhere: we should describe the problem and ask *how* to solve it; we shouldn't decide ahead of time the kind of thing (like a system or app) we expect will solve the problem and ask *what* within that category we should use.

For more specific guidance on how to ask for help with a problem in a non-shopping way, check out last year's ["I want to ask for recommendations, but that's off topic. Is there any way to ask my question?"](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5787/4398).

Comment: I'm not saying whether it's a good question or not, or if it should be closed for some other reason. Just that it's not a *shopping* question and is a useful example of how something that could easily be a shopping question can instead be asked in a way better suited to the Stack format.